# GEK does not automatically start new node after I delete a node from the GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I created a cluster:

```
gcloud container clusters create test
```

so there will be 3 nodes:

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME                                 STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
gke-test-default-pool-cec920a8-9cgz   Ready     <none>    23h       v1.9.7-gke.5
gke-test-default-pool-cec920a8-nh0s   Ready     <none>    23h       v1.9.7-gke.5
gke-test-default-pool-cec920a8-q83b   Ready     <none>    23h       v1.9.7-gke.5
```

then I delete a node from the cluster

```
kubectl delete node gke-test-default-pool-cec920a8-9cgz
node "gke-test-default-pool-cec920a8-9cgz" deleted
```

no new node is created.

Then I delete all nodes. still there is no new node created.

```
kubectl get nodes
No resources found.
```

Am I doing something wrong? I suppose it can automatically bring up new node if some node died.

Answer (score 4):

After running `kubectl delete node gke-test-default-pool-cec920a8-9cgz` run `gcloud  compute instances delete gke-test-default-pool-cec920a8-9cgz`

This will actually delete VM (`kubectl delete` only "disconnects" it from the cluster). GCP will recreate the VM and it will automatically rejoin the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes is a system for managing workloads and not the machines. Kubernetes node object reflects the state of the underlying infrastructure.

As such node objects are automatically managed by Kubernetes. "kubectl delete node" simply removes a serialized object from Kubernetes "etcd" storage. It does nothing to delete VM on GCE side where the kubernetes node is hosted. "kubectl delete node" is not meant to be used to remove nodes. Node pool itself carries the desired declared state, which cannot be altered by the "kubectl delete node" command.

If you want to remove a node you should [resize the instance group](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cluster-management/#resizing-a-cluster).